# is it normal in security that google saves my passwords to other sites which i signed up for it with the gmail?

Tags: security

Visiting https://passwords.google.com you can login to your gmail and view passwords that are managed by google. I visited It and saw multiple passwords for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter a new password on a site, Chrome will ask to save it. If you accept and click Save, Chrome saves your passwords depends on whether you want to store and use them across devices. When synced, passwords can be used on Chrome on all your devices, and across some apps on your Android devices.

When sync is turned on for passwords in Chrome, your passwords are saved to your Google Account.
otherwise, your passwords are only stored on Chrome on your computer.
It depends on your security concerns for turning off or on this feature on your chrome.